# MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Whenever I try to update the count of `value`, it shows the error:

```
MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'
```

Without the update function the code works fine, but using the update find in the put route gives the error.

I want to increment the value of an option in the polls object by 1 if its key value is equal to the value obtained through edit route

```
var express      =require("express");
var app          =express();
var bodyParser   =require("body-parser");
var mongoose     =require("mongoose");
var methodOverride=require("method-override");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/vtapp");
var pollSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    options:[{key:String,value:Number}]
});
var Poll=mongoose.model("Poll",pollSchema);

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    Poll.find({},function(err,allpolls){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.render("landing",{polls:allpolls}); 
        }
    });
});
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var name=req.body.name;
    var text=req.body.options;
    var arrops=text.split("\n");
    var newpoll={name:name,options:[]};
    arrops.forEach(function(opt){
        newpoll.options.push({key:opt,value:0});
    });
    Poll.create(newpoll,function(err,newp){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});
app.get("/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("new");
});
app.get("/pollshow/:id/edit",function(req,res){
    Poll.findById(req.params.id,function(err,foundpoll){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.render("show",{poll:foundpoll});
        }
    });
});
app.put("/pollshow/:id",function(req,res){
    Poll.findById(req.params.id,function(err,found){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            found.options.forEach(function(option){
                if(option.key==req.body.choice){
                    found.update(option,{$inc:{value:1}},function(err){
                        if(err) {console.log(err);}
                    });
                }
            });
            res.redirect("/pollshow/"+req.params.id+'/edit');
        }
    });
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT,process.env.IP,function(){
    console.log("Application is running");
});
```

If I'm not modifying the `id`, how is the error coming?

Comment: Were you able to detect where the error was coming from? I'm experiencing a similar error in my code...

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?